# How to display the selected value in dropdown list using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a drop down list

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
   <select class="form-control" id="question_type" name="agreement[question_type]">
      <option value="">Select Type</option>
      <option value="ss">Single select (checkbox)</option>
      <option value="ms">Multi option (radio)</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

After submitting the form I have placed this datas in table ,

```
<tr data-view-key="<?php echo $jagr_id; ?>">
   <td class="question_type">
   <?php
   if ($jagr_question_type == 'ss') {
       echo 'Single select (checkbox)';
   } else if ($jagr_question_type == 'ms') {
       echo 'Multi option (radio)';
   }
   ?>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#<?php echo $jagr_id; ?>" name="edit_agreement" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" title="Edit"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#<?php echo $jagr_id; ?>" name="delete_agreement" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="Delete"></span></a></td>
</tr>
```

and on the edit button click,i want to display the selected item in drop down list.
following code is used for edit click

```
$(document).on("click", "a[name = 'edit_agreement']", function(event)
{
   event.preventDefault();
   var jagr_id = $(this).attr("href").substring(1);
   var parent = $(this).parents("[data-view-key='"+jagr_id+"']");
   var question_type = parent.find("td.question_type").text();
   $("#hdn_jagr_id").val(jagr_id);
   $("#question_type option:selected").text(question_type);     
});
```

using  `$("#question_type option:selected").text(question_type);` i can display the text in the drop down list, but again submit the form the value not posted, Now the html part changed like this(repeating th eselected item)

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
   <select class="form-control" id="question_type" name="agreement[question_type]">
      <option value>Single select (checkbox)//selected item</option>
      <option value="ss">Single select (checkbox)</option>
      <option value="ms">Multi option (radio)</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @Guruprasad question_type is not an id,fetched the data from the table using ("td.question_type")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know what the `question_type` should be .. is it a text of option or value of option .. in all ways you need

```
.prop('selected' , true);
```

if `question_type` is a value of option

```
$("#question_type option[value='"+question_type+"']").prop('selected' , true);
```

if `question_type` is a text of option you can use .filter();

```
$("#question_type option").filter(function(){
   return $(this).text().trim() == question_type;
}).prop('selected' , true);
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/otxnjq3f/2/)**

Comment: var question_type = parent.find("td.question_type").text(); console.log( question_type); //output- Single select (checkbox)(selected item)

Comment: 'question_type' is text

Comment: @Ann Ok Ann I updated my answer if text and with simple demo as well

Comment: filter function not working,I have tried this code,the selected item not displayed in the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99269/discussion-between-ann-and-mohamed-yousef).

Answer (score 0):

This option worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#countryList").change(function(){

       var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

       console.log("You have selected the country - " + selectedCountry);

   });

});
```

Of course, you need to have HTML list of countries. Something like this:

```
<select id="countryList">
    <option value="1">USA</option>
    <option value="2">Brasil</option>
    <option value="3">Spain</option>
</select>
```